# Transitions on child components

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm building a basic SPA with transitions between pages. The transition between the pages works fine, however the child components don't run their transitions.

index.vue:

```
<template>
  <main class="animated">
    <text-content :content="content"></text-content>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import TextContent from '~/components/TextContent.vue'

export default {
  transition: {
    enterActiveClass: 'animated fadeIn',
    leaveActiveClass: 'animated fadeOut'
  },

  components: {
    TextContent
  },


  data() {
    return {
      content: {
        title: 'Title',
        body: '<p>Content</p>'
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And then my child component, TextContent.vue:

```
<template>
    <section class="container mx-auto my-14">
        <h1 class="mb-8">{{ content.title }}</h1>

        <div v-html="content.body">{{ content.body }}</div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  transition: {
    enterActiveClass: 'animated fadeInUp',
    leaveActiveClass: 'animated fadeOutDown'
  },

  props: ['content']
}
</script>
```

So the page fadeIn - fadeOut works great, but the TextComponents fadeInUp - fadeInOut doesn't.

Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transition` property is related to route transition only for components please use `<transition>` tag in template and use `appear` to run transition on initial rendering:

```
<template>
  <main class="animated">
   <transition  
         appear-active-class="animated fadeInUp"
         appear>
      <text-content :content="content"></text-content>
   <transition>
  </main>
</template>
```